# Setting an object's sub property using ILGenerator.Emit

Tags: c#, il, ilgenerator

I have some code that uses IlGenerator.Emit to create and populate a generic object using a datareader. It works great however I need to extend it to populate simple child objects when the database field name contains an underscore.

For example a database field named "Address_Line1" should populate the property Line1, which is a property of the Address property on the Entity. In C# code that basically...

```
Entity.Address.Line1 = "value from reader";
```

I tried writing c# code and used ILSpy to try identify the IL code I should be writing, but I keep getting memory errors etc.

The code below includes the current working IL code and I've included my code attempt with comments. Can anyone help me out?

```
public static DynamicBuilder<T> CreateBuilder(IDataRecord reader)
{
    var result = new DynamicBuilder<T>();
    var method = new DynamicMethod("DynamicCreate", typeof(T), new Type[] { typeof(IDataReader) }, typeof(T), true);

    var generator = method.GetILGenerator();

    generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(T));
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, typeof(T).GetConstructor(Type.EmptyTypes));
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

    var getValue = reader.GetType().GetMethod("get_Item", new Type[] { typeof(int) });

    for (int i = 0; i < reader.FieldCount; i++)
    {
        var name = reader.GetName(i).Split('_'); // MY CODE
        var propertyInfo = typeof(T).GetProperty(name[0]);

        if (propertyInfo != null && propertyInfo.GetSetMethod() != null)
        {
            var endIfLabel = generator.DefineLabel();

            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, typeof(IDataRecord).GetMethod("IsDBNull"));
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Brtrue, endIfLabel);

            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4, i);
            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, getValue);

            if (propertyInfo.PropertyType.Name.ToLower().Contains("nullable"))
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, GetNullableType(reader.GetFieldType(i)));
            else
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Unbox_Any, reader.GetFieldType(i));

            // START MY CODE TO GET THE SUB PROPERTY
            if (name.Length > 1)
            {
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, propertyInfo.GetGetMethod());
                propertyInfo = propertyInfo.PropertyType.GetProperty(name[1]);
            }
            // END MY CODE

            generator.Emit(OpCodes.Callvirt, propertyInfo.GetSetMethod());
            generator.MarkLabel(endIfLabel);
        }
    }

    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

    result.handler = (Load)method.CreateDelegate(typeof(Load));
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Have you tried emitting this code to an assembly and then running peverify on it?

Comment: Running peverify against the dll returns All Classes and Methods in my.dll Verified.

Comment: Not against the DLL that contains this code, against the emitted code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Code like this:

```
static Entity DynamicCreate(IDataReader reader)
{
    var entity = new Entity();
    entity.Property = (int)reader[0];
    return entity;
}
```

is compiled to IL that looks exactly like the code you're emitting (unimportant parts omitted):

```
ldloc.0     // entity
ldarg.0     // reader
ldc.i4.0    
callvirt    System.Data.IDataRecord.get_Item
unbox.any   System.Int32
callvirt    UserQuery+Entity.set_Property
```

But if you add that second property access:

```
static Entity DynamicCreate(IDataReader reader)
{
    var entity = new Entity();
    entity.SubEntity.Property = (int)reader[0];
    return entity;
}
```

Then the IL looks like this:

```
ldloc.0     // entity
callvirt    UserQuery+Entity.get_SubEntity
ldarg.0     // reader
ldc.i4.0    
callvirt    System.Data.IDataRecord.get_Item
unbox.any   System.Int32
callvirt    UserQuery+SubEntity.set_Property
```

Notice that the call to `get_SubEntity` is between `ldloc.0` and `ldarg.0`, not right before `set_Property` like in your code, so you have to move it there in your code too.

The reason your code doesn't work is that IL is a stack based language: when you call a parameterless instance method (like a property getter), the object on the top of the stack (which here is the result of the `unbox.any`) will be used as its `this`, which is not what you want here. Basically, your code tries to do something like:

```
entity.Property = ((int)reader[0]).SubEntity;
```

Comment: svick that fixed it :) Thank you very much for the detailed response!

Answer (score -2):

I'll suggest not use IL code/Emit at all since it is hard to build expressions with it. Instead try to use the new Roslyn to generate the delegates.

Here are some samples:
https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/Scripting-API-Samples